# Anything wrong with this exterior junction box?

Tags: electrical

I found some wiring that looks like a handyman did it and was wondering if I could get some input on why it may not be to code or a safety hazard. I think a circuit in the house was tapped and ran through the stucco. Are there any downsides to taking this approach instead of running EMT all the way from the breaker panel for a dedicated circuit?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you remove the cover and show what the wires/connections look like inside the box?

Comment: I'm guessing that location is outdoors and "wet". None of the 3 fittings attached to the box seems to be rated for wet locations, and the box itself may not be a weathertight type. Photos of the inside giving insight into how the wiring is terminated and how it passes through the wall would be helpful, as @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact noted.

Comment: The good news is that at first glance it looks like proper wire for wet locations, though the printing on the wires would provide the final answer to that - i.e., no NM cable, which was my big worry. However, there are green grounds even though it is all metal conduit. Which may be a sign of someone not knowing what they are doing because the metal conduit should be a valid ground path - why run 3 wires if you only need to run (and pay for) 2?

Comment: Great photos! None of those fittings or box are rated for wet and the bottom one even has stamped on it "dry loc only"! The conduit on the bottom seems to be AC or MC which are dry location only as well. Is this indeed outdoors and exposed directly to rain, or outdoors but covered and so perhaps "damp"?

Comment: It is covered by an eve so I believe its damp, thanks that was my suspicion also

Comment: Also, I think the green ground incoming needs to be bonded to the metal box (e.g. grounding screw) and only then connect to outgoing ground wires.

Comment: I'm only seeing 3 neutral and 3 ground wires.  So with the 3 visible conduits, it's very unlikely the electrician penetrated your stucco at the box to bring out a connection.  Now that 3 foot run from the middle conduit that goes into the wall, that's another matter.  I wonder if that location where the conduit goes into the wall was originally an outlet, and they brought that line out to this other box for additional connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Useful info on armored cable outdoors: (from afcweb.com)

> Questions are often raised about when armored or metal-clad cable can be used in wet versus dry locations
>
> What are wet, dry and damp location? The definition of a dry location
> according to the National Electric Code (NEC) is: A location not
> normally subject to dampness or wetness. A location classified as dry
> may be temporarily subject to dampness or wetness, as in the case of a
> building under construction.
>
> Based on this definition, standard Armored Cable (AC) or Metal-Clad
> Cable (MC) may be used in locations that may be temporarily exposed to
> the elements such as rain during construction.
>
> Dry locations are not to be confused with damp locations which are
> protected from the elements and water saturation but may be subjected
> to moderate amounts of moisture. Some damp locations may include open
> porches, barns, under canopies, etc.
>
> Wet locations occur in areas where direct burial in the ground, in
> concrete, etc may occur. These are areas where water or other liquid
> saturation is possible, or in areas that are regularly exposed to the
> elements.
>
> Options for wet and damp location cable Many questions center on what
> cabling products are approved for wet and damp locations. Type AC
> cable is approved by the NEC for use only in dry locations. In order
> to comply with the NEC for use in wet locations, interlocked Type MC
> Cable must have a corrosion resistant jacket and wet location rated
> conductors. A common style cable that is rated for wet locations is a
> standard MC Cable ***with a PVC jacket***. AFC Cable Systems® offers Parking
> Deck/Lot Cable which is UL Listed and rated for wet locations per NEC
> 330. Common applications for this cable include parking garages, direct burial, trenched and back-filled, swimming pools for pool
> motors and perimeter lighting and terminated in a pole base for
> parking lots and many more. PVC jacketed cable is also an ideal choice
> for locations where wiring is subjected to occasional dampness.

Of course, there are other options like appropriate conduit, but the key is wet-rated connectors/fittings/boxes and attention to penetrations.

I am not an expert, but if I were to try to "fix" this setup I would do the following:

1. Check for labeling on the wires to verify that they are labeled THHN/THWN or similar wet-rated.
2. Replace all the EMT fittings with wet-rated EMT compression fittings (often these have a blue plastic ring on them).
3. Replace the metal junction box with a weatherproof metal junction box (probably 2-gang size to give you plenty of room inside) and add a grounding pigtail wire connected to a grounding screw and the existing green wires.
4. Replace the corrugated AC/MC run with either EMT/wet fittings/THHN/THWN wire, or something like the PVC jacketed wet rated MC cable described above.

Of course, make sure the wires are sized appropriately for the circuit amperage (check the inside circuit it taps into also) and the conduit/box "fill" is big enough for the number and size of wires. There are also some rules for spacing of conduit support clamps etc.

Overall, this is not so bad as long as it doesn't get water on it.

Comment: thanks so the only problem you see is the lack of wet fittings and conduits right?